# Is it possible to do this in one MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

conversation_participants

```
id      | conversation_id | user_id
int(11) |  int(11)        |   int(11)
```

users

```
id      | username   | ....
int(11) | varchar(20)| ....
```

I am trying to select all the users which have a certain string in their username which are not (yet) participants in a particular conversation. Currently I have two SQL queries:

```
SELECT user_id FROM conversation_participants WHERE conversation_id=?
```

and

```
SELECT id, username from users WHERE username LIKE '%%%{$_GET['q']}%%' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

And remove all the results from the second query which have the same user_id as the ones from the first query. Is there any way to merge these two queries into one ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I really hope we're properly sanitizing `$_GET['q']` before we use it in an SQL query...

Comment: See below, this was just in test. I use mysqli prepared statements in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id, username from users 
WHERE username LIKE '%%%{$_GET['q']}%%' 
and username not in 
(
  SELECT user_id FROM conversation_participants 
  WHERE conversation_id=users.conversation_id
)
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Don't build your sql statements concatenating strings. You should use some sort of utility method to sanitize your input. Your statement is prone to sql injection attacks.

PHP has several functions for this. Look into [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Thanks ! Although this was not exactly what I needed it helped me figure out the query I needed. Here is my final (edited) query: `SELECT id, username
FROM users
WHERE username LIKE '%%%{$_GET['q']}%%'
AND id NOT
IN (
SELECT user_id
FROM conversation_participants
WHERE conversation_id = ?
)
ORDER BY id DESC`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answer I have to add, that you should not use $_GET (etc) parameters directly in your query without checking it for SQL injections.

Comment: Was just used purely in testing not in production, as you can see from my other query (the question mark) I use mysqli with prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a LEFT JOIN together with IS NULL

```
SELECT 
    u.id, 
    u.username 
from 
    users u
    LEFT JOIN
         conversation_participants cp 
    ON (u.id=cp.user_id AND cp.conversation_id=?)
WHERE 
    username LIKE '%%%{$_GET['q']}%%' AND
    cp.user_id IS NULL
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

I believe this is a more optimal solution than using NOT IN() and a sub-query for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use JOIN, which might be a bit faster.

```
SELECT u.id, u.username from users u LEFT JOIN conversation_participants c ON c.user_id = u.id WHERE u.username LIKE '%%%{$_GET['q']}%%' AND c.conversation_id != ? ORDER BY u.id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This query does not seem to work for me, firstly I get every user multiple time (but nothing which can't be fixed with DISTINCT) but also it does not remove the users which are already participants (which was the whole idea).

Comment: You're right. It wouldn't work if there are multiple entries for a user in conversation_participants table.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer, you could remove your "id" field in the table conversation_participants and define the 2 fields conversation_id and user_id as primary key.

Comment: Any particular reasons why this would be better ?